# Realm - Relationships 1 to n

Tags: android, realm

I have two tables (Dog & Person) defined in Realm object and need use 1:n relation.

My Person class is:

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {
        @PrimaryKey
        private int id;
        private int age;
        private Dog dog;
        /** Getters & setters **/
    }
```

My Dog class is:

```
public class Dog extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    public String name;
    /** Getters & setters **/
}
```

When the table "Dogs" contains data loading from internet. I need add dog id to my Person table as relationship, when save object Person. If save to "Person" table dogId, than i dont join data. I need select data from Person include dog name.

Is possible in realm as relationship? Or I use another realm query, where i will search by dog where id?

Thank you for response.

Comment: You don't have to join tables when using Realm. Let's say you need person with `id` 42. You query by `Person person = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("id", 42).findFirst();` The dog's name is then `person.dog.name`.

Comment: @geisshirt - I understand this, but i can save id? If is Dog class as datetype, i dont use integer id.

Comment: You might need to use `copyToRealmOrUpdate()`: https://realm.io/docs/java/1.1.0/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealmOrUpdate-E-

Comment: @geisshirt - yes, i use following:     
`realm.beginTransaction();`
        `Person person = new Person();`
        `person.setId(new Random().nextInt());`
        `person.setName("Person no. " + new Random().nextInt());`
        `person.setDog(*1*);`
        `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(person);`
        `realm.commitTransaction();`
But how to use id from Dog table?

Comment: If you already have a `Dog` object with id = 1, then you can do: `Dog dog = realm.where(Dog.class).equalTo("id", 1).firstFirst()`. You can use the object directly i.e., `person.setDog(dog)`.